# PHPStorm EAP update on Debian: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

Tags: java, intellij-idea, debian, phpstorm

When I start PHPStorm, this screen shows:

[Platform and plugin updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6BTm.png)

When I click on "Update and restart", after a few seconds this screen pops up:

[No space left on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4xMp.png)

Which is silly because this is a brand new computer and I have lots of available space:

```
➜  ~  df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       6.3G  3.4G  2.6G  57% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  9.1M  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G   55M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3       2.7G  364M  2.2G  15% /var
/dev/sda1       511M  132K  511M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda6       195G  4.7G  181G   3% /home
/dev/sda5       361M  7.4M  331M   3% /tmp
tmpfs           1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
➜  ~  df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       361M  7.4M  331M   3% /tmp
```

Here are my versions, for reference:

```
PHPStorm PS-143.129

Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit

Gnome 3.14.1
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Download and install full app instead of patch (has to be extracted into empty folder and not by just overwriting old files). https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: That's what I am currently doing, but there have been like 3 updates in the past week, I think it's a bit overkill for 2mb patches !

Comment: *"but there have been like 3 updates in the past week"* Nope -- no more than 1 EAP per week (sometimes only 1 per 2 weeks).

Comment: Alright, you got me there, once per week. But you're not answering my question at all, merely providing an alternative, that I'm already doing. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: Thing is -- that's the best solution I have found on JB forums/Issue Tracker -- all tickets for "No space left on device" (there were only few though) I have found had no feedback/resolution from devs except some had "I've tried again and it worked this time" from ticket authors. Similar solutions were on forum -- full install or try again.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Hope it gets fixed, I'll update my comment then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *kind of* avoiding the problem, but I've since switched to [Jetbrains Toolbox App](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/25/introducing-jetbrains-toolbox-app/) which solved this issue.